# Unload And load a reference at runTime

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a problem with the dll Oracle.DataAccess : on my workstation I have a client installed and on some server I have an other one. At the runTime I catch a

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. ---> 
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()
    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
```

In the catch clause, I would like to unload the current dll and load an other location (set in the config file).

Is it possible? And more than that, is it the good way of solving this problem?

Comment: You cannot unload a dll from an `AppDomain`; you can start an entirely *separate* `AppDomain`, but that is... "quite tricky"

Comment: Yes, this stop beeing a little hack for beeing a big change. Do you think I look in the wrong direction?

Comment: SELECT the assembly and go to properties-> SPECIFIC VERSION, set it to false. Try that if it works

Comment: It is already to false and it is not working

Comment: I am sorry. "Specific Version" is a build-time property.At run-time, the framework still looks for the specific version of the assembly that was used at build time.

Comment: It will first look in GAC and then in your bin. Why not add it your bin so that it always find the specific version that it was built with.

Comment: I have to choose a version at the compile time, so I am stuck! I don't want to make this choice at compile time. I want to be able to change it at runTime... Perhaps it is just impossible, and I should do conditional compilation?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to deal with it - abstract your oracle data access. Create two assemblies, each has reference to specific ODP. Determine which client installed or attempt to loading assemblies one by one until success and work trough your interface. But the key is, your client software must know only the interface, but the implementation of your ODP communication will be abstracted.

And there are patterns for this - proxy, decorator... you choose